# Built-in function to special method name for dictionary conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, oop

I've been delving into operator overloading and special methods within Python classes, and I noticed that many built-in functions have their equivalent special method names:

- `int(x)` calls `x.__int__()`
- `next(x)` calls `x.__next__()` or `x.next()` in Python 2

However, a couple functions, namely `tuple()` and `dict()`, do not have any equivalent. I am aware that the need has not arised yet for such special methods, but in some cases, a method for `dict()` conversion called on a class may be useful. How might I implement this? Or, what would you remark on someone attempting to use this kind of logic?

```
# I think this is quite interesting, so I shall post my own implementation of it as well
```

Comment: `dict` accepts *any iterable of pairs*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option 1: `__iter__`

Casting to `tuple` or `dict`, or any type that takes an iterable, relies on the `__iter__` method.

```
class ListOfKeys():
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def __iter__(self):
        for k in self.lst:
            yield (k, None)

lok = ListOfKeys([1, 2, 3])
d = dict(lok)

print(d) # {1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

The same will work for tuples.

```
t = tuple(lok)

print(t) # ((1, None), (2, None), (3, None))
```

### Option 2: `keys` and `__getitem__`

Alternatively, to cast to a `dict`, you can implement both `keys` and `__getitem__`.

```
class ListOfKeys():
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def keys(self):
        yield from self.lst

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return None

lok = ListOfKeys([1, 2, 3])
d = dict(lok)

print(d) # {1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

### Option 3: Both for supporting multiple types

Finally, if you want your class to have different behaviour for casting to a `dict` and a `tuple`, the following example demonstrates that `dict` will prioritize the `keys` and `__getitem__` solution.

```
class Foo:
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 1

    def keys(self):
        yield 2

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return 3

print(dict(Foo())) # {2: 3}
print(tuple(Foo())) # (1,)
```

Comment: `__iter__` or `__getitem__` to be precise.

Comment: That seems like the most pythonic way to do it. It's definitely cleaner than mine. Just a small comment though: What if one wanted to have different behaviour for dict(), tuple() and iter() alike? Say, iteration would only yield the values, not the pairs of values.

Comment: @NChauhan your approach is the correct one in this case, just get rid of the dunder naming! `.to_dict`, `.to_tuple`

Comment: @NChauhan dict actually prioritize the keys-getitem solution, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

In it's simplest form, I could try and retrieve `obj.__dict__`. I've also created a method, called `obj.__dictionary__` that returns a `dict`, but can customise what values are returned and how. I implemented a small function that tries to call `obj.__dictionary__` and other successive attempts at other methods:

```
def dct(obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if obj:
        try:
            r = obj.__dictionary__()
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                r = dict(obj)
            except TypeError:
                try:
                    r = obj.__dict__
                except AttributeError as e:
                    raise AttributeError(e) from None
                else:
                    return r
            else:
                return r
        else:
            return r
    else:
        return dict(*args, **kwargs)
```

For demonstration, a little class which encapsulates a `'Person'`:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, job):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.job = job

    def __dictionary__(self):
        return {'name': self.name,
                'age': self.age,
                'job': self.job,
                'title': '{} {}'.format(self.job, self.name)}

p = Person('bob', 42, 'farmer')
```

Now consider calling my custom `dct` function on a few objects to test it out:

```
>>> dct(p)
{'name': 'bob', 'age': 42, 'job': 'farmer', 'title': 'farmer bob'}

>>> dct(item='apple', quantity=5)
{'item': 'apple', 'quantity': 5}

>>> dct([('username', 'admin'), ('password', '123')])
{'username': 'admin', 'password': '123'}

>>> dct({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

As you can see, it seems to work in a decent way. I know that for my simple `Person` class demonstration, I could have simply returned `p.__dict__`, but I added an extra `p.title` attribute which only exists in `dict` form to show that this enables extra customisation. In addition, if I defined the `Person` class with `__slots__`, then the `dct(p)` call would fail with

```
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Obviously, I could extend the `try/except` blocks to attempt to access `__slots__` as well, but this is not the point I am trying to get across: If I defined the following in the custom `__dictionary__` method, the code would
work as expected:

```
def __dictionary__(self):
    return {name: getattr(self, name, None)
            for name in self.__slots__}
```

Comment: What's the point of pretending that the language implements some hook that it doesnt? The `dict` constructor doesn't support it, so why not just simply a `to_dict` method?

Comment: For ease, I could call `dict()` on anything and not need to worry whether it has its own `to_dict` method

Comment: Then wrap it in `try: return obj.to_dict() except AttributeError: return obj.__dict__`... my main point is you shouldn't be adding your "own special" dunder methods. In fact, this is specifically proscribed in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: [Any use of `__*__` names, in any context, that does not follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers)